# Eclipse "Waiting for Crashlytics" never resolves

Tags: eclipse-plugin, crashlytics

On first run crashlytics ran fine and asked for my username/password. Now the icon just sits there 50% transparent and hasn't resolved after sitting there inactive for 2+ hours. How am I supposed to get around this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Help > Install New Software...***

The issue was the download url I was using. A staff member at crashlytics reached out to me via email and helped me figure out what the issue was - *thanks Mike!*

**DO NOT USE** http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse

After updating with the following location everything worked great:

## https://crashlytics.com/download/eclipse